# Tableau : Decimal numbers interpreted as null value in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Im new on Tableau Desktop.

I was starting to import data from a csv. file.

Some columns don't display decimal number, but instead, null value.

And I check, format is the good one (number with decimal).

In my csv. file, I can see my column with values :

[image]

And in Tableau :

[image]

Sometimes, data appears and sometimes not, that's weird.

So, What option do i choose ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: edit your axis in a suitable range like 0.001 to 0.009 , its a bit of trial and error but you can understand

Comment: CSVs can be a little pernickety if not well formatted. Dodgy field separators can cause misplaced columns (is the separator in this CSV a semicolon?) and hidden rogue characters can prevent Tableau recognising the correct column format. Sometimes worth forcing all import fields to be text (temporarily) as this allows text functions in tableau to be used to identify any rogue characters.

Comment: Thanks! What file format should I use (other than .csv)?

Answer (score 0):

Your data range is the issue here. You can right click on the Y-axis and edit the axis

[image]

Comment: Not that's it. I made a sum of my values, so I think, it should be like 40.0002 for example.

Comment: In any case, you can manually edit the ranges

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I don't think so that is the ranges. Sometimes, my value are detected as null, sometimes not. I tried to change the language setting to consider my numbers.